# How to get a static vector of data.table column names

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to create an *immutable* vector of a data.table object's names, which won't change after using `setnames`. For example, I want to create a version of mtcars.names that will stick with `"mpg"` instead of `"miles.per.gallon"` here:

```
mtcars.dt <- data.table(mtcars)
(mtcars.names <- names(mtcars.dt))
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
[11] "carb"
setnames(mtcars.dt, "mpg", "miles.per.gallon")
mtcars.names
 [1] "miles.per.gallon" "cyl"              "disp"             "hp"
 [5] "drat"             "wt"               "qsec"             "vs"
 [9] "am"               "gear"             "carb"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mtcars.names <- copy(names(mtcars.dt))
setnames(mtcars.dt, "mpg", "miles.per.gallon")
mtcars.names
## [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
## [11] "carb"
```